# How can I update single field of an item in database using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a to-do list using PHP and MySQL as a beginner project and I am trying to add the ability to post status updates to individual items in the list to a column in the database called 'notes'. I have been unable to figure out how to specify in the  update query, the specific item in the list that I am trying to update. The query I have updates the 'notes' column for all of the items in the database. Can someone please help with this?

```
<?php 
            if (isset($_POST['notes'])) {                                   
                $input = $_POST['notes'];
                $id = $row['id'];

            $sql = "UPDATE tasks SET notes ='$input' WHERE id = ($id)";  
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
              } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
              } } ?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaEFS.png)

Comment: How/where do you get `$row['id']`? ... should that be `$_POST['id']` instead? Side note, you are wide open for SQL injection issues, strongly advise to use parameterized queries.

Comment: The $row['id'] is from the select query I use to populate the fields on the web page. I should have included that code also: 

 "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE category = 'project'");
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) { while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?> 

 When I replace $row['id'] with $_POST['id'] I get an error: "Warning: Undefined array key "id" in C:\xampp\htdocs\My2dolist\projects.php on line 65 Error: UPDATE tasks SET notes ='update code' WHERE id = ()" 

The 'id' field on the web page is being populated by a value from the database. It is not an input.

Comment: Then it might be better to update the code based on what you said. Anyway, try a `echo $sql;` before the `if` to see what the query looks like with the code that you have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send what to update in the notes column, you have also sent that particular row id, using this id you can update that particular record in the table

For this, you have store this id in the hidden field in your form tag

```
            $id = $_POST['id'];  **// Changes here**
```